# Как подсчитать трафик странички?

Tags: php

Народ, скажите, пожалуйста, как подсчитать трафик страницы. Допустим, у меня есть страница 
index.php. На ней есть какой-то текст и картинки, как мне подсчитать размер страницы со всем ее и содержимым. Если можно, покажите, как это дело делается.

Answer (score 1):

Способ 1.

Отключаете кэширование в браузере.
Открываете инспекцию (`inspect/analyze element`) в зависимости от браузера ее положение может меняться.
Открываете вкладку "Сеть". Перезагружаете страницу.
Вам выводится размер загруженного материала и время загрузки.

Способ 2.

`get_included_files()` возвращает массив файлов, которые были добавлены.
Список JPG можно выцепить из готового HTMLника.
Суммируете значения `getfilesize`.

Answer (score 0):

Если быстро, то сложи все файлы, которые грузятся по запросу страницы (картинки, стили, скрипты, библиотеки, html самой страницы), в папку и посмотри, сколько она весит.